# User & Role management for Neo4J community

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I am new to Neo4J. I built a few graphs in the Desktop edition and now trying to move them to cloud (AWS). I have an EC2 instance setup and Neo4J community edition is loaded.

I wish to create user roles and uses before I give access to other.

All the documentation related to roles and users is for the Enterprise Edition. I think there is only user management available for Community Edition and that too all the users get ADMIN access.

Any work around to create roles and assign users to them using community edition?

Comment: nop ... that's why there is the enterprise edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and community edition only has ADMIN role. So all the uses you create are ADMIN's. In order to restrict access, we need to find a hack like building an interface on Neo4J.

The Enterprise edition lets you create users and assign different roles.

A few resources comparing Enterprise edition and Community Edition
https://neo4j.com/subscriptions/  (Scroll to the middle of the page)